# Phone Number Regex

Tags: c#, mysql

I need a regular expression for phone number which includes country code, area code and phone number.The phone number format should be exactly like: `001-253-3478887` or `90-312-4900203`.
I try this but it does not work. What should be the correct format? How can I get the phone number info?

```
(\(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}
```

Comment: Surely the number format will depend (at very least) on the country code?  If not, why bother storing them formatted?  Why not just store the digits and then format in your presentation layer?

Comment: Will you have other country codes? Some country codes are 1 or 4 digits, so you could have numbers such as
1-253-3478887
or
1-001-253-3478887.

Also, why are you storing one with leading zeroes, but not another? In other words, how is the country code going to be formatted?

Comment: It can be any country I don't know how to check and write regex which is appropriate for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^((\d-\d{3})|(\d{1,3}))\-\d{3}-\d{7}$
```

This regex will match all country codes. Country codes of 1 and 1-684 won't be valid in the other answers. It will also prevent country codes such as 1-42 from being allowed, since the only time there should be a separator in a country code is when it's four digits long. If you end up getting 4 digit country codes without the separator, use the following instead:

```
^((\d{4})|(\d{1,3}))\-\d{3}-\d{7}$
```

Answer (score 2):

this will work based on the two examples you gave,

```
 ^\d{2,3}\-\d{3}-\d{7}$
```

Comment: Just a shame that won't match a single UK telephone number.

Comment: @eggyal my answer is based on the example given, there are so many combinations of telephone number. how do i know it all? maybe the OP needs to be specific on the question.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
\d{2,3}\-\d{3}\-\d{7}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out:

```
((\d{2,3}-))\d{3}-\d{7}
```